# How do I check for an error after [NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:]?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsdata, memory-mapped-files

I have this code in my project:

```
id mappedData = [dataWithContentsOfMappedFile: path]
```

Obviously, if `mappedData` is nil it didn't succeed. But how can I get details about *why* it didn't succeed? There's no `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:withError:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:`, passing the `NSDataReadingMapped` constant in the options parameter.

(This constant is known as `NSMappedRead` if you're not compiling against the iOS 4.0 SDK.)

Comment: Oh. I just assumed that the options wouldn't include mapped I/O. Thanks!